# Why multiple records is not updating using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am giving my controller code below :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($club_open); $i++) {
    $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["club_id"] = $club_id;
    $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["days"] = $club_open[$alpha[$i]];
    $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["open_time"] = $club_open_time[$alpha[$i]];
    $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["close_time"] = $club_close_time[$alpha[$i]];
    $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["status"] = $club_status[$alpha[$i]];
    $this->ClubOpenDay->updateAll(
      array('ClubOpenDay.status' => "'".$infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["status"]."'"),
      array('ClubOpenDay.club_id' => "'".$club_id."'")
    );
}
```

using this code, I am not able to update multiple records. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this:

```
$this->ClubOpenDay->updateAll(
  array('ClubOpenDay.status' => "'".$infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["status"]."'"),
  array('ClubOpenDay.club_id' => "'".$club_id."'")
);
```

write the following:

```
$this->ClubOpenDay->updateAll(
  array('ClubOpenDay.status' => $infomation["ClubOpenDay"]["status"]),
  array('ClubOpenDay.club_id' => $club_id)
);
```